# PrimeNG Calendar. Как узнать текущее значение календаря?

Tags: angular

Использую PrimeNG компонент Calendar. Как узнать текущее значение календаря? т.е. пользователь может менять месяц, год. Мне нужно узнать какой месяц и год на данный момент видит пользователь

Comment: у календаря есть свойство `value`, получаешь доступ к инстансу через `ViewChild(Calendar)` и стучишься к `calendar.value`

Comment: в calendar.value - будет установленное значение которое установил пользователь. Это значение я получаю через ngModel. Напр. пользователь выбрал дату 12.06.2020. Потом в календаре перешел на месяц Май. Мне нужно получить Май. Как?

Comment: `calendar.currentMonth`. А в чем проблема слушать события дополнительно `on${UNIT}Change`?

Comment: calendar.currentMonth и calendar.currentYear - то что нужно. Спасибо!!!